# Can a final class extend other classes in java?

Tags: java

I know that a final class cannot be extended but I just want to know whether or not a final class can extend other classes (Just out of curiousity).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It can't.  Just try it yourself to see.

Comment: Every class except of the Object class extends some other class. For example, Double is final and it extends Number.

Answer (score 2):

Just 4 lines to test that

```
class NonFinal {
}
final class Final extends NonFinal {
}
```

<sub>and one more line to compile</sub>
<sup>even less if extending some standard class</sup>